# Can typescript export a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax, typescript-module-resolution

Is it possible to export a simple function from a typescript module?

[This isn't compiling for me.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=module%20SayHi%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09console.log%28%22Hi%22%29;%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0Anew%20SayHi%28%29;%0A)

```
module SayHi {
    export function() {
    console.log("Hi");
  }
}
new SayHi();
```

[This workitem](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/47) seems to imply that you cannot but doesn't flat out say it. Is it not possible?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're going for in that example. `exports =` is about exporting from *external* modules, but the code sample you linked is an *internal* module.

Rule of thumb: If you write `module foo { ... }`, you're writing an internal module; if you write `export something something` at top-level in a file, you're writing an external module. It's somewhat rare that you'd actually write `export module foo` at top-level (since then you'd be double-nesting the name), and it's even rarer that you'd write `module foo` in a file that had a top-level export (since `foo` would not be externally visible).

The following things make sense (each scenario delineated by a horizontal rule):

---

```
// An internal module named SayHi with an exported function 'foo'
module SayHi {
    export function foo() {
       console.log("Hi");
    }

    export class bar { }
}

// N.B. this line could be in another file that has a
// <reference> tag to the file that has 'module SayHi' in it
SayHi.foo();
var b = new SayHi.bar();
```

---

**file1.ts**

```
// This *file* is an external module because it has a top-level 'export'
export function foo() {
    console.log('hi');
}

export class bar { }
```

**file2.ts**

```
// This file is also an external module because it has an 'import' declaration
import f1 = module('file1');
f1.foo();
var b = new f1.bar();
```

---

**file1.ts**

```
// This will only work in 0.9.0+. This file is an external
// module because it has a top-level 'export'
function f() { }
function g() { }
export = { alpha: f, beta: g };
```

**file2.ts**

```
// This file is also an external module because it has an 'import' declaration
import f1 = require('file1');
f1.alpha(); // invokes f
f1.beta(); // invokes g
```

Comment: Thanks, the `exports function blah()` syntax is what I was looking for

Comment: Four years later, I believe it would make much more sense if "export" was called "public" instead...

Answer (score 16):

To answer the title of your question directly because this comes up in Google first:

**YES, TypeScript can export a function!**

Here is a direct quote from the TS Documentation:

"Any declaration (such as a variable, function, class, type alias, or interface) can be exported by adding the export keyword."

[Reference Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

Answer (score 13):

If you are using this for Angular, then export a function via a named export. Such as:

```
function someFunc(){}

export { someFunc as someFuncName }
```

otherwise, Angular will complain that object is not a function.

Edit: I'm using angular 11 now and this isn't needed anymore. So it's enough to `export function someFunc(){ ...}`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I'm doing it like this:

```
 module SayHi {
    export default () => { console.log("Hi"); }
 }
 new SayHi();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `from` keyword with `import` and destruct the exported object directly.

> file1.ts

```
export const CARS_QUERY = `
    {
      getAllCars {
        model,
        make,
        picture
      }
    }
    `;
```

> file2.ts

```
import { CARS_QUERY } from "file1.ts";
```